# Multisite - Save the draft only to the site it was created in

Tags: multi-site, craft4

I'm working on the multisite in Craft4 - 2 identical sites, but the text is in different language. I have a section with the **Propagation Method** set to `Save entries to all sites enabled for this section` and all **Fields** set to `Only save blocks to the site, they were created in`.

Our process is to create an entry and add all the content in one site. Once the article is ready, we would like to have that article saved with all the content into the other site. From this point, all adjustments/translations should be made only in the site, it is adjusted in.

The problem is, that the entry content is duplicated into the other site only once, when the Entry or Draft is created. All the other adjustments to the entry content is saved only in the site, it was created in.

Is there an option to work on the content in the "Draft mode" and all the adjustments that we made in the Draft are saved in both sites? Once the Entry is created, all other adjustments will be saved only in the site, it is adjusted in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable workaround could be to change your section's "Propagation Method" setting to "Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to". With that propagation method, Craft won't automatically create the entry in the other site for you; i.e. you can create the entry (i.e. draft) in site A, prepare its content, and then once it's ready to go, you can create it yourself in the other site by using the "Add a site" button in the entry's sidebar (at which point the content will be duplicated from the original entry).

[image]

Comment: You're a Genius :). Thanks a lot!!